# Displaying the "IE7" version of a site on Mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile-safari, proximity

I was trying to use this code on a site:
[Proximity Effect](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/04/thumbnail-proximity-effect/)

Works great in all supported browsers, and falls back to a grid of thumbnails on IE7/8. The downloadable code looks like they are using conditional comments for IE.

The problem is, mobile Safari passes the checks and shows the full version, but of course the iPad had no roll over event.  So nothing happens.

I'd be happy to show the grid (IE7) version to mobile devices, and the full version for modern desktop browsers.  How would you recommend putting in the test for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some JavaScript to detect mobile device and browser.

```
if( 
(
  navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ||
  navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) ||
  navigator.userAgent.march(/iPad/i)
) && 
(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1)
){
  // your code
}
```

Also, if you know exactly what element or script is not working in mobile Safari, you could test for that instead of checking a specific browser.

Note: userAgent for Safari will include "Safari", but not "Chrome", when Chrome will include both.